# Python: How to scan stderr or stdout of a subprocess and perform an action if the string is found?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

The below code fails to exit after 3/3 even though the stderr text  `[ERROR] ssh target does not support password auth` pops up in my linux terminal. I believe the text is stderr output due to the following line from Hydra's source code:

***hydra module "ssh.c" source code snip:***
`fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] ssh target..`

It appears that my program is not properly scanning stderr for the string. The variable `output` is supposed to capture this output, which I then want to "grep" for an occurrence of the [ERROR] string. If it's found I want the program to exit (instead of running 20k login attempts against an invulnerable service).

Any help is  appreciated.

**My code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "Usage: sshrecon.py <ip address> <port>"
    sys.exit(0)

ip_address = sys.argv[1].strip()
port = sys.argv[2].strip()

print "INFO: Performing <<TEST>> hydra ssh scan against " + ip_address 

#3 steps for test phase:
#1 Run Hydra 
#2 Gather std_err std_out output into a var
#3 analyze for String. Exit if found, else continue with full scan.

#[1/3] TEST if target allows PW auth
HYDRA_TEST_COMMAND = "hydra -l test -p test -f -o /var/www/html/recon_scan/results/labs/%s_test.txt -u %s -s %s ssh" % (ip_address, ip_address, port)
results_Test = subprocess.Popen(HYDRA_TEST_COMMAND, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

#[2/3]Gather stderr, stdout output into var
output = results_Test.stdout.read()
print output

#[3/3]analyze std_out for string. Exit if found.
if "ssh target does not support password auth" in output:
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not capture the result of `stderr`.

```
results_Test = subprocess.Popen(
    HYDRA_TEST_COMMAND,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True)
```

Because `stderr` is not redirected, only `stdout`, your program will not be able to read it.  Your two choices are to mix `stderr` and `stdout` into one single stream, or to capture them separately.

If you want to combine both `stderr` and `stdout` into one stream,

```
results_Test = subprocess.Popen(
    HYDRA_TEST_COMMAND,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
```

If you want separate streams,

```
results_Test = subprocess.Popen(
    HYDRA_TEST_COMMAND,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True)
```

### Use shell=False

Using `shell=True` is not recommended in general, because it can lead to potential unexpected behavior or attack vectors.  Alternatively, you can pass the arguments as a list instead of a string, and then you can use the default (safer, faster) `shell=False`.

```
HYDRA_TEST_COMMAND = [
    'hydra', '-l', 'test', '-p', 'test', '-f',
    '-o', '/var/www/html/recon_scan/results/labs/%s_test.txt' % ip_address,
    '-u', ip_address, '-s', port, 'ssh']
```

If `port` is an `int` you will need to use `str(port)` instead.

There are cases where `shell=True` is more convenient but they are rare in practice.

This might not affect how your program works, but it eliminates problems with quoting or weird characters in filenames.  If you don't like how verbose it is you can make it a bit shorter with `.split()`.

### Use .communicate()

Instead of `proc.stdout.read()`, use `proc.communicate()`.

```
# instead of results_Test.stdout.read()
stdout, stderr = results_Test.communicate()
```

If you used `PIPE` for both `stdout` and `stderr`, this gives you the contents of both in separate variables.  If you use `.stdout.read()` instead, the process can become blocked waiting for you to read from `.stderr.read()`.  That's the primary job of `.communicate()` -- it reads from both `stderr` and `stdout` at the same time so the process doesn't block.

If you use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, then `stderr` will be `None` because the contents are mixed into `stdout`.

In either case, it is recommended to use `.communicate()`.